# Error when add mirror in disk management window server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, mirroring, mirror

I have a problem when add mirror in disk management window server 2012

The problem is:

> The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console
> view is not up-to-date. Refresh the view by using the refresh task. If
> the problem persists close the Disk Management console, then restart
> Disk Management or restart the computer

I already reinstall disk and restart server but problem still persist
It seems problem is by partition, not by disk because of i do a test by created a small other partition of first disk and mirroring to second and result is OK

The details of partition and error as below:

List of volume: https://ibb.co/FbrN7NC
Error when add mirror: https://ibb.co/qjCpNqs

If someone went through this problem, please give me your advice

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Encountered same problem in Win10, and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/801868/add-mirror-for-volumes-other-than-the-last-one-in-windows-7-disk-not-up-to-dat) answer lead me to the solution: make sure the partition you're trying to mirror is the LAST one on the disk, i.e. extend it to cover up any free space that's sometimes left behind after shrinking
or deleting other partitions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shrink and extend again can solve this problem